# Easy date time picker in Django

Tags: python, jquery, django

I'd like to have several datepickers in some of my pages.
I have followed the guide in the following link for Fengyuan Chen’s Datepicker (last one):
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html

If I create a standalone html page with the code provided, it's all great!
I don't understand how to embed the date time picker in other pages though.

All of my html pages extend a base. And I put in the base head all of the contents like so:

`base.html`:

```
 <head>
    /* some unrelated things*/
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>

    <!-- Fengyuan Chen's Datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-b88RdwbRJEzRx95nCuuva+hO5ExvXXnpX+78h8DjyOE=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-/7FLTdzP6CfC1VBAj/rsp3Rinuuu9leMRGd354hvk0k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
```

Then, in the page that I need to have the picker in:

```
    {% extends 'main/base.html' %}
    <input id="datepicker">

    {% block myBlock%}
        <script>
          $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker();
          });
        </script>
    {% endblock %}
```

in my views

```
def test1(response):
    
    return render(response, "main/test1.html", {})
```

The result is that I get an input field that does not move at all.

I find frustrating the fact that many guides are for standalone pages and not so many describe embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the easiest way to include date pickers is to rely on `input type 'date'`

I know it may be sometimes visualized differently by different browsers, but the important thing is that it does what I want it to do: let the user pick a date.

```
html page

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}        
    Start date 
    <input type = 'date'  name='start_date' value={{defaultDates.start}}>
    End date 
    <input type = 'date'  name='end_date' value={{defaultDates.end}}>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="setDateRange.end">Set Date Range</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <input> elements with type="date" do not show as any date field/calendar in IE11 and earlier versions

Comment: @Blackranger you are completely right, but my application will not be accessible over the internet. It'll be an lan-only website. All users have versions of browsers that do understand type="date". So I will stick to it although you are indeed right.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using any kind of model or form use it like this in html file this doesn't have anything to do with Django load that function before:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Datepick</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
</body>
</html>
```

and if you are using form or model you can use widget:

```
from django.forms.widgets import DateInput
class dateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = date
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'dob':'Date Of Birth',
        }
        widgets = {
            'dob': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```